# PDF: how to convert one column lists to multiple column data frame? - lists of people in subgroups inside groups to multiple columns

Tags: r, list, pdf, text-mining

I have near 15 PDFs containing **lists of people**. This PDFs are only one column width, so it is a pure list. But in some way these lists are nested (subgroups inside subgroups inside groups...). There is no numerical data apart from the first number of each person in the list (which is very important for my analysis), and similar order info.

I need to pull out from the PDF this lists and convert them into a conventional data frame.

Here is an example of the structure of one PDF:

```
TERRITORY ONE
1. GROUP ONE
1. Name Surname
2. Name Surname
3. Name Surname
4. Name Surname
2. GROUP TWO
1. Name Surname
2. Name Surname
3. Name Surname
4. Name Surname
TERRITORY TWO
(...)
```

This is the first PDF: http://bocyl.jcyl.es/boletines/1983/04/02/pdf/BOCYL-D-02041983-1.pdf

---

**!!!** I found these documents also stored in the webpage, so in HTML format: http://bocyl.jcyl.es/html/1983/04/02/html/BOCYL-D-02041983-1.do
Maybe it is easier to take the content from them instead from the PDF?

---

This follows as you can imagine (territory two, three, four..., with subsequent subgroups one, two, three, four,... etc.). This goes up to near 600 lines per PDF and more in the latest PDF.

I need to create a data frame that follows this example structure:

```
   PERSON    |    TERRITORY  |  GROUP  | POSITION IN LIST
Name Surname | TERRITORY ONE | GROUP 1 |         1
(...)
Name Surname | TERRITORY ONE | GROUP 2 |         4
(...)
Name Surname | TERRITORY TWO | GROUP 1 |         3
```

**One row should be one person**

`POSITION IN LIST` should refer to the order in which person `Name Surname` appeared in a given year (each PDF is for a year), in his `TERRITORY`, in his `GROUP`.

Consider it to be something like a ranking, in which is important the order of the person.
Very few of the people of the PDF1 (year 1) will appear again in PDF2 (year 2), and then in PDF3 (year 3), etc. So, one objective behind all of this is to know how many and who does repeat year after year in this list.

And also, it is important for the analysis to know the position of that person who does repeat in every year, to draw the evolution of this person, or to know if this person disappears after year X, etc.

PS: pardon my English, is not my first language :(

Comment: It would make it a lot easier to help you if you could share one of these pdf's to make this reproducible. You can use dropbox, Github or Google Drive.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the comment! I added one of the PDFs.

Comment: Hi there. This is a big job. There's really two parts to this. Firstly there's reading in all the data from the PDFs into R, which you probably want to do programatically rather than manually. This page might help: https://data.library.virginia.edu/reading-pdf-files-into-r-for-text-mining/
  
Then (the 2nd part) there's mining the text from the objects you've just created, cleaning it and getting into the format you need.

Comment: I've started working on an answer for you @pbstckvrflw but it is going to take a while! Looks like there is some horrible `stringr` work with regexps going to be required!

Comment: There will be errors that will need to be manually fixed here if you do this programatically. Even in the one PDF you have shared, there is a problem on p20 (Zamora) where the second party listed (PARTIDO COMUNISTA DE ESPAÑA PARTIDO COMUNISTA DE CASTILLA- LEON) does not have a "2." before it.

Comment: It would be helpful to know if every territory listing will begin with the string "JUNTA"

Comment: Yes! Every territory starts with "JUNTA ELECTORAL DE". @FrancisBarton

Comment: Having the data from HTML instead of PDF is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fuller answer, based on scraping the web page rather than the PDF, and still only using one source. So, not yet tested with more than one web page to scrape. If you have additional web pages of source data then add them to the vector at the top of the code below.

I may leave that as an exercise for you @pbstckvrflw!

This was a lot of work but luckily I enjoyed doing it and learning stuff as I went.

However **please note** that tasks of this scale are not usually appropriate for SO questions, and it is better to try hard to make your own attempt at a solution and then ask very specific questions about problems you discover.

I hope you can read carefully through the code I have written and try to understand what is happening at each step. The main thing you may need to learn is about `map` and how it can apply a function to every item in a list. I have used `map` extensively here because we're working with nested lists. There are also some good regexps.

It's far from perfect code and there may be errors or inefficiencies. It would be better if some of it were decomposed into repeatable functions. And it generates several intermediate objects, which is a bit messy, but that's just the way it is. Partly the code is in blocks for clarity, partly because I don't have any more time to integrate the blocks into a more fluid workflow without excessive risk of things breaking.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(conflicted)
conflict_prefer("pluck", "purrr")

# you should add any further URLs to this vector
urls <- c("http://bocyl.jcyl.es/html/1983/04/02/html/BOCYL-D-02041983-1.do")

# scrape text from the relevant part of the webpage
# (assume that any additional URLs have the same structure)
text <- urls %>%
  map(., ~ {xml2::read_html(.) %>%
      rvest::html_nodes("#presentDocumentos p:not([class])") %>% 
      html_text})

# extract a manageable name from the URL and use it to name each text
names(text) <- urls %>% 
  str_extract_all(., pattern = "(?<=/)BOCYL.*(?=\\.do$)")

# do any manual fixes for errors in source data
text1 <- text %>% 
  map(., ~
  str_replace_all(., "PARTIDO COMUNISTA DE ESPAÑA PARTIDO COMUNISTA DE CASTILLA- LEON", "2. PARTIDO COMUNISTA DE ESPAÑA PARTIDO COMUNISTA DE CASTILLA- LEON"))

text2 <- text1 %>%
  map(., ~ 
        str_replace_all(., "(\\.)*(\\s)*$", "") %>% 
        str_replace_all(., "(\\s)+", " ") %>% 
        str_replace_all(., "^Suplente.*", "") %>% 
        str_c(., collapse = ";") %>% 
        str_split(., pattern = "JUNTA ELECTORAL DE ") %>% 
        map(., ~ tail(., -1) %>% 
              str_split(.,
                        pattern = ";(?=\\d{1,2}\\.\\s([:upper:]|\\s){2,})") %>% 
              set_names(str_to_title(map(., 1))) %>% 
              map(., ~ tail(., -1))
        )
  )


text3 <- text2 %>% 
  map(., ~
        map(., ~ 
              map(., ~ str_split(., pattern = ";(?=\\d{1,2}\\.\\s)") %>% 
                    set_names(map(., 1) %>% 
                                str_extract(., pattern = "(?<=\\d{1,2}\\.\\s)[:upper:].*")) %>% 
                    map(., ~ tail(., -1) %>% 
                          enframe(., name = "list_position", value = "person_name") %>% 
                          mutate_at(
                            vars("person_name"),
                            ~ str_extract_all(.,
                                              pattern = "(?<=\\d{1,2}\\.\\s)[:alpha:]+.*"))))))

text4 <- text3 %>% 
  map(., ~
        map(., ~ 
              map(., ~
                    map_df(., c, .id = "political_group"))))

text5 <- text4 %>% 
  map(., ~
        map(., ~ 
              map_df(., c, .id = "territory")))

# EXAMPLE
# To look at just the data frame produced from the first web page supplied
# (with columns rearranged as desired):
data_frame1 <- text5 %>% 
  pluck(1, 1) %>% 
  select(person_name, everything())
data_frame1
```

I have pushed the latest code to [the GitHub repo I made](https://github.com/francisbarton/tidy_spanish_elections).
If you are happy with this answer to your question, please tick this as the accepted answer.

Comment: This solves my problem, I'm really thankful! I'll take note of what you say about SO, this was my first time here so also the last time this way! I have learned a lot with your answer, indeed. I have other problems for the 'future', as the latest HTML as far I see have another format (and also I need to keep the string 'Suplente' for everyone that is indeed a substitute) so your answer gave me a really really good start You're a great person for giving me your time!

Comment: Good luck! Keeping the "Suplente" will be a headache! It might be easiest to export the `text` to a csv file or something and edit it in Excel by hand to do this, then re-import the data for the rest of the script. You can use the `readr` tools `write_csv` and `read_csv` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite a full answer but it gets you some of the way. Go through it step by step and see what happens with each line. You'll be able to use `purrr::map` to apply the steps to a list of pdfs etc. I've just taken the text of the first/only pdf here (`text[[1]]`) in order to keep things relatively simple.

I would like to tidy up and streamline the code a bit more, and add more comments, but wanted to reply as soon as I was ready.

Unfortunately due to problems with reading in the PDF and creating a `dput` text chunk I can't provide a reprex but you should be able to amend the following to get you started:

```
library(here)
library(pdftools)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

# download.file(
#   url = "http://bocyl.jcyl.es/boletines/1983/04/02/pdf/BOCYL-D-02041983-1.pdf",
#   destfile = here("pdfs", "BOCYL-D-02041983-1.pdf"),
#   mode = "wb"
# )

pdfs <- list.files(path = here("pdfs"), pattern = "pdf$")
text <- map(pdfs, ~ pdftools::pdf_text(here("pdfs", .)))

# be better to combine these into a single piped function (mappable)
# we need to combine the text into a single block before editing and splitting
text1_combined <- str_c(text[[1]], collapse = "")
text1_split <- str_split(text1_combined, "JUNTA")
# remove header text
text1_split <- text1_split[[1]] %>% tail(-1)
# repair text lost from str_split
text1_list <- map(text1_split, ~ paste0("JUNTA", .))

# extract territory name and use it to name each sub-list
text1_list <- text1_list %>% set_names(., nm = str_extract(., "^([:upper:]|\\s)+(?=\r)"))
text1_trimmed <- map(text1_list, ~ str_replace(., "^([:upper:]|\\s)+\r\n", ""))

text1_trim_tidy <- map(text1_trimmed, ~ str_replace_all(., "\r\n(?=[:digit:])", ","))
text1_trim_tidy <- map(text1_trim_tidy, ~ str_replace_all(., "\r\n", " "))
text1_trim_tidy <- map(text1_trim_tidy, ~ str_replace_all(., "\\s+$", ""))

text1_by_party <- map(text1_trim_tidy, ~ str_split(., ",(?=[:digit:]+\\.\\s[:upper:]{2,})"))


# clear up intermediate objects
# rm(text1_combined)
# rm(text1_split)
# rm(text1_list)
# rm(text1_trimmed)
# rm(text1_trim_tidy)
```

Hopefully I will edit this or add another answer once I have tidied up the code some more. I made a github repo [here](https://github.com/francisbarton/tidy_spanish_elections) for further reference.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing, thanks!  I have just replicated all the code and I partially get what is being doing here, and it's going the way I like!  Just another point of: my objective is to put all of this as a data frame in which every row is only one person, so that given X person as first column, the following columns should be the Junta (territory), then the Party, then the position of X person in the list. With the R lists, would I be able to do this, to create a data frame in that sense?

Comment: Yes sure we can definitely get to the result you want. I just wanted to post my partial answer soon (before someone else does!) I thought maybe you can do the rest yourself but I will keep working on it too - I'm learning as well. The code I've written so far is not very good but it at least takes you step by step. Hopefully you can understand some of the steps.

Comment: Okay, I'll follow your updates, so I can learn from this way to do it, thank you!